# Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts. prisma

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma, next.js13

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "seed": "npx prisma db seed",
    "prettier-fix": "prettier --write '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json,html}'",
    "generate-sitemap": "ts-node --project tsconfig.sitemap.json lib/generateSitemap.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.2",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.5",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^13.4.8",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.10.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-hover-card": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.1.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.7",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "framer-motion": "^9.1.7",
    "lucide-react": "^0.292.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "^13.2.1",
    "next-auth": "^4.19.2",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prisma": "^4.10.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.48.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.5.3",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "sitemap": "^7.1.1",
    "swr": "^2.0.3",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "usehooks-ts": "^2.9.1",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.2",
    "@types/next": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.1",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.3",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "@types/react-tagsinput": "^3.19.9",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^13.1.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.3",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@/schema/*": ["./schema/*"],
      "@/lib/*": ["./lib/*"],
      "@/components/*": ["./components/*"],
      "@/store/*": ["./store/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Error i am getting is :
yarn run v1.22.21
$ /Users/sagarmochi/Desktop/projectmate/node_modules/.bin/prisma db seed
Environment variables loaded from .env
Running seed command `ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts` ...

An error occurred while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.